# How to write a Python console program can output like the top command in Linux?

Tags: python

The output of top command in Linux like bellow:

> Tasks: 158 total,   1 running, 157 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>   Cpu(s):  6.3%us,  3.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.9%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,
>   0.0%st Mem:   8264212k total,  2637492k used,  5626720k free,   299884k buffers Swap:  4192924k total,        0k used,  4192924k free,
>   2010332k cached
>
> PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>   7178 mysql     15   0 52876  31m 4680 S 21.3  0.4 308:12.04 mysqld
>   2262 www       16   0 28092  11m 4764 S  4.0  0.1   2:02.31 php-cgi
>   2110 www       16   0 27956  11m 4888 S  3.7  0.1   2:04.51 php-cgi
>   2005 www       16   0 28680  12m 4872 S  3.0  0.2   2:04.10 php-cgi
>   1955 www       16   0 28476  12m 5220 S  2.7  0.1   2:06.51 php-cgi
>   2030 www       16   0 28260  11m 4872 S  2.0  0.1   2:05.27 php-cgi
>   7044 www       15   0 24348  19m  932 S  0.7  0.2   1:58.38 nginx

Only part of the content changes constantly.

I can only output a single line keeps changing constantly without newline:

```
import  sys
import  time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('i = %d.\r' % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
```

I want to know how to output multiline like the top command(keeps changing constantly without newline).

Sorry, My English is poor. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Qi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use a library for handling the interaction with the console, e.g. http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html